# How to get my image drawn on a canvas proportionally, yet not leave any borders when the window is resized

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am currently in the process of making my website. I would like it to be interactive and have a nice design.
What I am currently doing is just drawing an image onto my canvas, with a bit of JavaScript that will resize my image proportionally as the window is resized. However, when I resize it to the smallest browser size, or the largest browser size, since it is proportional, it leaves a white border at the side.

I have already tried using CSS to fill the webpage by using `'width: 100%'` and `'height: 100%'` or `'width / height: auto'` but that doesn't seem to change anything. I have also tried other resize functions (to below). but they are all very similar, if not the same.

```
img.onload = function () {
    ctx.canvas.width = img.width;
    ctx.canvas.height = img.height;

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  resize();
};

function resize() 
{
    var ratio = canvas.width / canvas.height;
    var canvas_height = window.innerHeight;
    var canvas_width = canvas_height * ratio;
    if(canvas_width>window.innerWidth)
    {
        canvas_width=window.innerWidth;
        canvas_height=canvas_width/ratio;
    }

    canvas.style.width = canvas_width + 'px';
    canvas.style.height = canvas_height + 'px';
}
```

Taken from: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VNjwYE

What should happen is that the image takes up the *whole* canvas with no borders at the sides. However, as I said, there are white borders at the side of image.
This imgur album has two screenshots of the problem. https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvW6l.jpg

The rest of the code (i.e. CSS and HTML) can be found on my Codepen: https://codepen.io/DreamingInsanity/pen/aPoJEK

Thanks,
Dream.

Answer (score 2):

just add `body{ margin:0px; }` in your css,

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();

img.src = "https://source.unsplash.com/2000x1000/?trees,nature,forest";

img.onload = function () {
    ctx.canvas.width = img.width;
    ctx.canvas.height = img.height;

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  
  resize();
};

function resize() {
    var ratio = canvas.width / canvas.height;
    var canvas_height = window.innerHeight;
    var canvas_width = canvas_height * ratio;

    if(canvas_width>window.innerWidth)
    {
        canvas_width=window.innerWidth;
        canvas_height=canvas_width/ratio;
    }

    canvas.style.width = canvas_width + 'px';
    canvas.style.height = canvas_height + 'px';
}

window.onresize = resize;
```

```css
html, body {
    background-color: #1A1919;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    margin: 0px;// do it 
}

#canvas {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    filter: grayscale(0%);
}


#top_bar {
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>My Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Home/Stylesheet.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Home/Buttons.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script src="Scripts/Canvas.js"></script>
    <div id="top_bar"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Adding that does nothing. Also, where do you see it in my code? I can't find where 'margin' exists.

Comment: sorry it's not in you code, it's saw it in style of that page, and when i made `0px` it work file, may be it added somehow, did you try to use `!important`?

Comment: Unfortunately, it still does nothing.

Comment: please see the answer, i edit it, is it that what you want

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but no. It still has the white border around the edge, like in my imgur album.

Comment: but in here `snippet` doesn't show any border even your `codepen`

Comment: can you show me the css of that page like `html, body {...` ?

Comment: The CSS of my page is exactly what you posted most recently.

Answer (score 0):

I changed what code editor I was using and at the same time, neetened up my file structure. As you can see in the HTML I am looking for the CSS under `/Home/` whereas now, I am looking for it under `/CSS/`.

Comment: firstly thanks to you for findout the problem. the problem was, you were editing the wrong file. when i face this kind of problem like i write the right code but it's not working nothing, in that time i use one trick to find out: i write simple code in that file like make a unique color or give a console then come back to the browser after that i can easily understand this file is working or not. sorry for talk more but i think it will help you or other. :)